# Modulo arithmetic proof

Tags: modular-arithmetic

**Show that if none of the numbers in the list 1a,2a,..(p-1)a are congruent to 0 mod p, then no two numbers in the list are congruent to each other mod p.**

I am not sure how to try to demonstrate this.

So far i got nowhere. Can someone point me in the right direction or explain me how the proof?

Comment: I would assume that p is a prime number based on the notation but it's not specified anywhere.

Comment: If $ia\equiv ja$ where $1\le i\lt j\le p-1$ then $(j-i)a\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where $c,d \in \Bbb N$: Suppose for contradiction that there are $ca,da \in \{1a,2a,\ldots,(p-1)a\}$ such that $$1 \leq ca < da < p$$ (the above is true by necessity for any $ca,da$ you pick -- I'm just making it explicit) and 
$$ca \equiv da \mod p$$
That is:
$$da - ca \equiv 0 \mod p$$
I.e.
$$(d-c)a \equiv 0 \mod p$$
But since $1 \leq ca < da$, we know that $da -ca \geq 1$, whereby $$(da-ca) = (d-c)a \in \{1a,2a,\ldots,(p-1)a\}$$
But we assumed that no numbers in the set are equivalent to $0 \mod p$. But $(d-c)a$ contradicts this. Thus, our proposition must be false, and there can't be $ca$ and $da$ such that $ca \equiv da \mod p$.

Comment: Let this answer take me to over 9000 rep

Comment: Done. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Cheers :-)

Comment: @AdrianChiriac You're welcome!

Comment: What?!  You're OVER $9000$?! :-P

Comment: And me here stuck at $999\ldots$.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, no, this does not require the assumption that $p$ is prime. Hint: let $1 \le i<j<p$, and assume $ia\equiv ja \mod p$. Subtract.

Comment: I tried that but I got stuck at a(j-i)=0 mod p. (j-i) is in (Zp)

Comment: You have $1 \le j-i < p$, now look at your assumption.

Comment: So I was on the right track. It makes sense. My assumption was that none of the numbers is 0 mod p.=> contradiction. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ia \equiv ja \bmod p, i < j$.  Then $ja-ia = (j-i)a$ is divisible by $p$.  Now $a$ and $p$ are coprime, for if they shared some common factor $f$, then $(p/f)a < pa$ would be divisible by $p$ and therefore $\equiv 0 \bmod p$.  But if $a$ and $p$ are coprime, and $(j-i)a$ is divisible by $p$, then $j-i$ is divisible by $p$.  Since $j-i < p$, it cannot be divisible by $p$ and our assumption that $ia \equiv ja \bmod p$ must be false.

Comment: You're quite welcome!

Comment: No longer stuck at $999$ ;-)

Comment: Ha ha thanks. :-)